# chmod allowing write when I am not setting it

Tags: permissions, find, chmod

I've got a perl script which systematically changes permissions. The first thing the script does is remove all permissions. It does this by calling `chmod`(from perl). I did this as I found the set guid bit wouldn't clear unless I explicitly cleared it:

```
system('find',
        $topdir,
        '-exec', 'chmod', 'u-swrx,g-swrx,o-swrx', '{}', ';'
);
```

I set different permissions for groups and directories. Using `find`, I call it from perl as follows (in this case for directories):

```
system(
    'find',
    $topdir,
    '-type', 'd',
    '-exec', 'chmod', 'g=rx', '{}', ';'
  );
```

Now even though I only set rx, when I check file permissions after the script has finished executing, the scripts appear to have rwx. Is there something I should look out for, as I don't quite follow why this is happening; I don't explicitly set it anywhere. I do set ACLs as well, but they all behave as expected. The only thing of note I see when I check with getfacl is `mask::rwx` and `default:mask::rwx`. Could that be what is causing the problem?

Comment: As a note, there's a native perl `chmod`, and a core `File::Find` module that works recursively much like `find`.  Kind of tidier and probably more flexible, etc.  Plus `File::Find` is worth learning how to use.

Comment: As you call `chmod` for all objects anyway (first `find` call) it makes sense to leave out find completely and use `chmod -R ...` instead (unless you are not root but then you should call `find` with the option `-depth`). The second call can be a lot faster by using `-exec +` (if your `find` supports that). For debugging I recommend that you call chmod (via `find -name`) for a single file and run the perl script through strace. That should tell you what happens at the system level.

Comment: Try doing the `chmod g=rx file` for some file, and look what happens. Perhaps you aren't allowed to change permissions (you can change them _only_ on your objects, unless you are root).

Comment: And just to be sure, you're not trying this on FAT32 or similar (i.e., a filesystem which doesn't support permissions)?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the error output: you should be seeing `` find: `…' Permission denied `` errors. The first thing you do is remove all access permissions from `$topdir`, which prevents recursing further into it. None of the `chmod` commands you expect are executed except for the very first one.

If you want to remove the permission to access all the directories in a tree, you need to do it from the inside out. Otherwise, once you've cut yourself off from the parent directory, you can't recurse into it any more.

```
system('find',
        $topdir,
        '-depth',
        '-exec', 'chmod', 'u-swrx,g-swrx,o-swrx', '{}', ';'
);
```

Since you're using Perl, use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) instead of calling the external program `find`. Use the `finddepth` function to get the right traversal order.

It seems pointless to do two traversals. Instead, do a single traversal and directly set the file permissions to what you want, e.g. `chmod 0750` or whatever it should be. Using `File::Find` will give you greater flexibility to e.g. treat directories and regular files differently.